# C++ Boost Library Symbols not found for arm64 | M1 Macbook

Tags: c++, macos, boost, clion, arm64

After installing Boost via HomeBrew and writing the following code :

```cpp
#include "Common.hpp"

/* ----- B00ST ----- */
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

void Common::generate_random_password(std::string* password, int length) {
    /*
     * INPUTS :
     *      Pointer to store the generated password
     *
     * OUTPUTS :
     *      None
     *
     * RAISES :
     *      None
     */

    std::string chars(
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            "1234567890"
            "!@#$%^&*()"
            "`~-_=+[{]}\\|;:'\",<.>/? ");
    boost::random::random_device rng;
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> index_dist(0, chars.size() - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        password->append(&chars[index_dist(rng)]);


} // generate_random_password(const std::string* password)
```

CLion's coming up with this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "boost::random::random_device::random_device()", referenced from:
      Common::generate_random_password(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int) in Common.cpp.o
  "boost::random::random_device::~random_device()", referenced from:
      Common::generate_random_password(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int) in Common.cpp.o
  "boost::random::random_device::operator()()", referenced from:
      int boost::random::detail::generate_uniform_int<boost::random::random_device, int>(boost::random::random_device&, int, int, boost::integral_constant<bool, true>) in Common.cpp.o
      unsigned int boost::random::detail::generate_uniform_int<boost::random::random_device, unsigned int>(boost::random::random_device&, unsigned int, unsigned int, boost::integral_constant<bool, true>) in Common.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I've tried to reinstall Boost, double checked my CMake file but I see nothing wrong with my actual building configuration...

In case, here's my CMakeLists.txt file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(Banko)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
add_executable(Banko main.cpp Common.cpp Common.hpp)
find_package(Boost 1.80.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Banko ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Thanks for your time  !

Unguest

Comment: Not that it solves the linking problem, but can't you use `std::random_device` and `std::uniform_int_distribution`?

Comment: Note: Using `random_device` as a generator may be slow. `random_device` is often used to seed a PRNG and use that to generate pseudo random numbers instead.

Comment: Homebrew puts include-files in /usr/local/include on Intel-based macs and /opt/homebrew/include om ARM-based macs. That might be an issue.

Comment: Meant library-files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the binaries you used was build for x86_64 architecture only.
You can check the architecture of build binaries using this command:

```
lipo -info /usr/lib/libName.dylib
lipo -info /usr/lib/libName.a
```

You can build universal libraries and check again.

[Here is how you build universal binaries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157483/macos-build-universal-binary-2-with-cmake)

If you are using Xcode you can also exclude arm64 architecture if that fulfils your requirement.